# Does Edge show in the Google "Recently used devices" list as "Safari 537.36"?

Tags: windows-10, safari, microsoft-edge, google-accounts

The Google Account "Recently used devices" list shows a sign-in from Safari 537.36 on Windows.  However, I don't use Safari (and [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)#Safari_5) the last Windows version of Safari was in 2010).  Microsoft Edge (Windows 10) has been used to log in to the account, and I am thinking Google is incorrectly recognizing Edge as Safari.  The Edge User-Agent string does include `Safari/<ver>` per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx).

Can anyone confirm or deny my hypothesis?  Any official statements from Google on their algorithm for parsing User-Agent strings?

Comment: @Ramhound So your Edge shows as "Edge" on the "Recently used devices" list?  Or as something else?  Thanks!

Comment: @cxw - `Browser (Edge) Hide details` - Yes; Yes it does.  `Browser (Chrome) Hide details` - Worth pointing out, the user agent for Chrome, also reports `Safari 537.36` in the details.  I never click the details when I view the recent used connections.

Comment: @cxw - The current answers already cover my statement.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, it's your rep total :) .  But you have directly inspected the "Recently used devices" page, which the other answers have not (as far as I can tell).  I think yours is quite pertinent to my question and deserves to be an answer, at least for the benefit of any future readers.

Comment: @cxw - I don't write answers for reputation.  I write answers ot answer questions.  This question has two accurate answers.  It doesn't need my 3 sentence answer with a screenshot, that answer, wouldn't add anything that hasn't been said already

Answer (score 2):

According to [this list of Edge user agent strings](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/tools/user-agent-parser/browse/browser-name/edge-user-agents)—reproduced below—the answer is yes: If you see a user agent string such as Safari 537.36, you *might* be using Edge. Why “might?” Read on…

As for why this is done, my head is still spinning from my basic research, but according to this [Pro Webmasters post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83804/why-does-the-internet-think-microsoft-edge-is-google-chrome) as well as [this blog post](https://www.allenpike.com/2015/user-agents-of-change/), it seems like Microsoft Edge developers are attempting to get Edge to be recognized by apps that “sniff” user agent strings as a “modern browser.” Thus the “Safari/537.36” and “Chrome/39.0.2171.71” seem to be declarations or browser capabilities and compatibility.

So for all intents and purposes, Edge is desperately saying, ***“Hey! I’m not Internet Explorer! I can do cool stuff like other modern web browsers!”***

---

And here are those headache inducing Edge user agent strings.

#### Edge

- Edge on Windows 10 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0
- Edge on Windows 10 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0

#### Edge 20.1

- Edge 20.1 on Windows 7 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240
- Edge 20.1 on Windows 10 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240
- Edge 20.1 on Windows 8.1 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240
  Edge 20.1 on Windows 8 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240
- Edge 20.1 on Windows XP - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240
- Edge 20.1 on Windows Vista - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240
- Edge 20.1 on Windows 10 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240

#### Edge 25.1

- Edge 25.1 on Windows 7 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
- Edge 25.1 on Windows 10 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
- Edge 25.1 on Windows 8.1 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
- Edge 25.1 on Windows XP - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
- Edge 25.1 on Windows 8 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
- Edge 25.1 on Windows Vista - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
- Edge 25.1 on Windows 10 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
- Edge 25.1 on Windows Phone 10.0 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 950) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586

Comment: Thanks for the research!  I like (but weep at) Pike's note "every HTTP request Edge makes has to include more than 150 bytes of text to simply convey that it is in fact Edge" - up from 109 bytes when I wrote [this](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/289807/105281) last year.

Comment: Interesting... since Edge is only available on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty normal for a browser to have many entries in the "User Agent" strings.  Navigate to this website to see what Edge normally reports as

http://www.useragentstring.com/

Answer (score 0):

Edge on Windows 10 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0

Comment: Pleases add an explanation to this answer.